# Two Layer 3 Switches to one router

Tags: cisco, routing, layer3

So I have a cisco 2811 router and 2 3560 switches

Currently the router is connected to Core1 only, what i would like to do is use the other port on the router  (fa0/1) to connect to Core 2.

How do I go about doing this? The router currently has the ip 192.168.1.1 and 
Core 1: 192.168.1.251 
Core 2: 192.168.1.252

I tried to make another interface on the router but it complained that the ip address that I set conflicted with the one of fa0/0 to Core 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable IRB (integrated routing and bridging) on the two router ports.  You create, in essence, a L2 bridge between them.  You then put the IP address in the BVI (bridge virtual interface).

Be sure to enable spanning tree, as you are creating a second L2 path.

Comment: Please could you give me an insight as to the commands I would need to enter?

Comment: This [document](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/integrated-routing-bridging-irb/17054-741-10.html) should be able to help you out with getting IRB configured.

Answer (score 0):

As router is layer3 devices .Hence each interface connected and configured with each networks .

In this scenario both core1 & core 2 switch are connected with two router interface with same networks ip address 192.168.1.X . That's the reason getting ip address conflict error while other router port configured .

To avoid this error configure another networks address to another router interfàce .