# Can cisco router interfaces be configured to be L2 interfaces?

Tags: router, cisco-ios

Can cisco router interfaces be configured to be L2 interfaces? Like

> #no switchport

command turns L2 port to L3 port at cisco switches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a layer 2 interface, you have to configure Integrated Routing and Bridging.  See [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47558/two-layer-3-switches-to-one-router) for more details.